# Shoddy and horrible audio performance and support on Raspbian Lite

Tags: audio, alsa, raspbian-lite

My audio on the Raspberry Pi 1 (Yes, I have an original model) on my Raspbian 10 Lite installation works, but only barely. Allow me to explain.
I picked Raspbian 10 because I wanted to set up my own window manager environment instead of using an off the shelf desktop environment on my Raspberry pi, because I wanted better performance. I have the window manager working just fine, but my audio support is all over the place.

- Audio seems to work OK with `speaker-test`...
- But if I try to compile a Quake source port called Qurp, it complains it can't find `bcm.h` or something. I know that header is related to the audio because I've seen "bcm" appear in all sorts of Alsa configuration stuff.
- If I try to listen to music with `cmus`, it takes forever to launch despite being a tiny terminal program, and when I finally get in, find a song, and hit enter to play it, the entire program freezes and no audio is played.
- I have Doom set up on my Pi via `chocolate-doom`. It works OK unless I have audio enabled. If audio is enabled, it keeps complaining in the console about some `pcm underflow` or something, and the game runs extremely choppy even at the lowest resolution available, and the audio is extremely choppy and unbearable too. But, if I turn off all the audio through `chocolate-setup`, the game runs fine.

All I did to set up Alsa was to install some Alsa packages as I saw fit. I suppose I clearly didn't do enough to set it up properly, because it runs about as well as a morbidly obese lobster with no legs, and I can't seem to get anything that makes use of audio for more than a second to work right. 
How do I set up and configure audio support on my Raspberry Pi 1 manually, so that it works consistently and doesn't crash entire programs?

I'm away from my Pi right now, but I'll be back later today.

Comment: Have you tried running on a later version of hardware? Does that make any difference?

Comment: I've had good experiences with newer raspberry pis in the past, it's just this very first one that I'm having issues with.